# What are some available software packages for automated finding of local and absolute minima on PES?

Tags: software-recommendations, machine-learning, potential-energy-surface

I have never used any AI driven calculation package before and to be honest don't fully understand the ins and outs of it. To be more specific I'm looking for something that can find local minima for molecules along with an absolute minima. I would like to get some quick exposure to some available packages (maybe some pros/cons) so that I can get a better idea of what exactly would be the ideal package for me.

Please let me know what is available for this, and what exactly I should be looking out for (ie: ''Make sure you find AI driven not Monte Carlo based'').

I would like to avoid calculating the whole PES, and would like to arrive at the minima more directly.

Comment: +1. Only a few more questions/answers and you fulfill commitment! The question might need some clarification. You want to avoid actually calculating the PES point-by-point in say, MOLPRO?

Comment: [CREST by XTB](https://xtb-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/crestversions.html) is my newest favorite algorithm for exploring PESs. They also have metadynamics which can explore the PES (not sure how it is different from CREST).

Comment: @NikeDattani Yes, the main goal is to avoid point-by-point calculations. I can edit the question to clarify it some more if you think that will help.

Comment: Yes please do make it clear. So basically you want the local and absolute minima without calculating the whole PES? Then why does the title suggest that you want to calculate a PES? I'm a bit confused, but I think when you clarify the question I'll no longer be confused!

Comment: I have used Basin Hopping and a generalization known as temperature basin-paving monte carlo to characterize the minima of water clusters in the past. Water clusters are sort of the most difficult version of this problem that I am aware of. This type of method could definitely be used relatively easily with e.g. proteins as long as you have a relatively fast potential. Basin hopping doesn't search point-by-point because it performs a minimization at each step, but this is still very expensive. Doing a minimization is impossible to avoid though in this context.

Comment: I also don't understand why you're mentioning AI? I am aware of efforts to do global minimization using machine learning, but these are ongoing and there is very little published research in this area.

Comment: @CodyAldaz - meta dynamics is part of the CREST default algorithm. It's described succinctly in the [manual](https://xtb-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/crest.html#imtd-gc-algorithm)

Comment: I have bad experiences with using semiempirical methods for finding lowest energy conformers. Users beware... semiempirical is only fast, not accurate... In my case I compared 75 conformers, ranked using MM94, PM7 and HF/6-311G and MP2-aug-cc-pVTZ. MM94 was the closest. PM7 was terrible. HF/6-311G was alright (this assumes MP2/aug-cc-pVTZ as baseline - even MP2 may not be accurate enough but it was a  25 atom molecule, I wasn't going to use THAT much computer time...)

Comment: @B.Kelly - we just published a pretty thorough evaluation of over 600 molecules against DLPNO-CCSD(T) energies: https://doi.org/10.1002/qua.26381 (open access) Suffice to say that PM7 is not good, but GFN2 is an excellent balance of speed and accuracy. I would definitely not trust HF since dispersion interactions are critical for conformed energies.

Comment: It's good to see so much good discussion here. In an effort to prevent this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/353643/391772, if the system complains about too much discussion going on in comments, please do not click the button that creates a *new* chat room, and use this chat room which is specifically for potential energy surfaces: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117652/spectroscopy-potentiology

Comment: @GeoffHutchison that is a nice paper, however, speed doesn't matter, only accuracy. 1kj/mol error wrecks a chemical reaction. it doesn't appear to be the case that any method (aside from ccsd or maybe MP2) meets this requirement :( #globalminima is hard.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [Atomic Simulation Environment](https://wiki.fysik.dtu.dk/ase/) has two nice implementations of global optimization algorithms. The first is a [basin hopping algorithm](https://wiki.fysik.dtu.dk/ase/ase/optimize.html#module-ase.optimize.basin) from a [1997 paper](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/jp970984n) by Wales and Doye in *J. Phys. Chem. A*. The second is a [minima hopping algorithm](https://wiki.fysik.dtu.dk/ase/ase/optimize.html#minima-hopping) from a [2004 paper](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.1724816) by Goedecker in *J. Chem. Phys*. There are several nice example use-cases [here](https://wiki.fysik.dtu.dk/ase/tutorials/tutorials.html#global-optimization).

If you're looking at relatively simple organic molecules, I agree with a prior comment that [CREST](https://xtb-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/crest.html) is a nice code for sampling lots of conformations to find low-energy structures, which uses the semi-empirical [xTB](https://github.com/grimme-lab/xtb) code as a driver.

I should clarify though that finding a global minimum is easier said than done, and the success of any method will depend a lot on the various degrees of freedom for your system.

Comment: +1. Lots of useful information in there, as usual! I'm quite glad this question got answered actually, as it seemed simple yet got left without answers for months. Also I'm especially happy to see that 1997 paper by Wales and Doye mentioned, since Jon Doye was the internal examiner for my doctoral thesis at Oxford!

Answer (score 4):

### Bayesian Optimization

There are some nice options for exploring potential energy surfaces using [Bayesian optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_optimization). This has the advantage of using [Gaussian Process regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_process) to build a surrogate to the potential energy surface

Bayesian optimization works extremely well for "expensive" functions (e.g., minutes to hours per point) in which the overhead of performing the GPR is offset by efficiently exploring the potential energy surface - perfect for first principles calculations.

My group has some efficient methods for finding the global minima, but not exploring the entire PES.

You might want to check out BOSS by the [Aalto group](http://cest.aalto.fi/):
https://cest-group.gitlab.io/boss/tutorials.html
e.g.
["Efficient Cysteine Conformer Search with Bayesian Optimization"](https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.15006)

They find a >10x speedup over a genetic algorithm.

Comment: Awesome. This answer has a lot of useful information indeed!